# Reasons to use an inline style?

Tags: html, css

What would be some good reasons to have to use inline style as oppose to an external css file or css code in the header?

Comment: Maybe if you're generating the document via a serverside language and the element's CSS code varies too much (like a `width`)? I've yet to encounter one.

Comment: Nothing more than simple convenience, that ultimately clutters up your HTML, and should be avoided.

Comment: It's convenient sometimes, there's no way to deny that. Otherwise it wouldn't be part of the HTML standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One good reason to use inline styles is if you're using it for HTML emails.  For every other opportunity, I think it would be best to use external styles with meaningful classes/ids and inheritance.

Comment: I thought emails supported the `<style>` tag, so how's inline styles better than that then?

Comment: @Diego the `<style>` doesn't work in the gmail web-client (it strips it out).  Refer to http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ for more information, it gets updated fairly frequently.

Comment: Enough with the flames. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Not all styles can be reused; some will be used by a single element in the HTML, so having a class for that may be an overkill and even increase the overall size of the file.

Using inline style can actually make HTML more readable and maintainable when the style can't be reused for other elements (tags).

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to find a way to avoid inline styles.  They are often indicative of poor planning or lazy programming.  That being said, they are available.  Don't beat yourself up for using the tools that are available to you if a specific need arises.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is to make the HTML less readable and the CSS less maintainable. Not all styles can be reused; some will be used by a single element in the HTML, and having a class for that may seem like overkill and can slightly increase the overall size of the file - but having two different places where you have to edit the CSS makes things as a whole harder to maintain. This difficulty increases exponentially as you add more and more inline styles.

Moreover, while making changes, finding and navigating to the right HTML file to modify the inline CSS when you make a change to something else in your stylesheet can be a hassle and increases the effort of applying those changes. That's the definition of poor maintainability.

Comment: Not to mention the performance advantage of rendering one style, and the referencing it many times, rather than just rendering that style many times.

Comment: My answer was an edit of Diego's to provide the other side - but there *are* limited uses of inline style, like HTML emails as Matthew says.

Comment: What about styles that **can't be reused**, as I am talking about in my answer?

Comment: @Diego: What about them? They belong in a stylesheet. Can you give an example of why they do not?